# Why value doesn't want to change?

Tags: c#, private, indexer

I got a portion of code to hold game variables.

The `Var` struct is a simple one:

```cs
struct Var{
/// <summary>
/// Name of variable. Unchangable
/// </summary>
public string Name { get; private set; }
/// <summary>
/// Value of variable. Can be changed via <see cref="Change(string)"/>.
/// </summary>
public string Value { get; private set; }

public Var(string s, string value) {
    this.Name = s;
    this.Value = value;
}


public void Change(string v) {
    new Debug("b", $@"Changing value from ""{Value}"" to ""{v}""", Debug.Importance.ERROR);
    this.Value = v;
    new Debug("b", $@"Result: ""{Value}""", Debug.Importance.ERROR);
}
}
```

(`new Debug(string, string, Debug.Importance)` is a function that simply calls `Conosle.WriteLine()` without `using System` in each file)

class `GameVars` is a list of those.

I use an indexer for getting a `Var` using a variable.

```
public string this[string s] {
    get => vars.Find(e => e.Name == s).Value;
    set {
        new Debug("a", $@"Attempt to change value of ""{s}"" to ""{value}"".", Debug.Importance.ERROR);
        if( vars.Find(e => e.Name == s).Name != null )
            vars.Find(e => e.Name == s).Change(value);
        else
            vars.Add(new Var(s, value));
        new Debug("a", $@"Result: ""{this[s]}""", Debug.Importance.ERROR);
    }
}
```

And when in `GameVars.LoadFromFile(string s)` I use

```
this[ident] = value;

new Debug("", $"When do i Fire? {this[ident]}", Debug.Importance.ERROR);

if( this[ident] != value )
    throw new System.Exception("Could not change value!");
```

I get following output:

```
[ERROR]( a ) Attempt to change value of "version" to "beta 0.0.0.1".
[ERROR]( b ) Changing value from "beta 0.0.0..1" to "beta 0.0.0.1"
[ERROR]( b ) Result: "beta 0.0.0.1"
[ERROR]( a ) Result: "beta 0.0.0..1"
[ERROR](  ) When do i Fire? beta 0.0.0..1
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in ITW.exe
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in ITW.exe
Could not change value!
```

Why isn't the value changing?

I tried changing everything to public and nothing helped. I checked everything with `Console.WriteLine()` and there is nothing to override this value. It just does not change to new one.

[Minimal runnable code on Rextester](https://rextester.com/ANQR27095)

Comment: FYI, the "bracket getter/setter" is called an ["indexer"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/).

Comment: Thanks. Did not know. TIL.

Comment: Also known colloquially as an "indexed property".

Comment: value isnt a reserved word for the language? perhaps it isnt the problem but i think you are actually trying to access Value instead of value (i mean in the gamevars )

Comment: @nalnpir where do you mean that?

Comment: Can you reduce this to a standalone console app that can be copied/pasted and debugged as-is so we can observe the behavior?

Comment: I'll try to do so.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't want to change because it enjoys being at the old value.

Comment: I made minimal runnable code and put it on Rextester (online c#) and changed throwing exception a bit faster there, becuase that's the first moment, when its different.

Comment: In the code on Rextester, `Var` is a struct. But above, `Var` is a class. That matters, because `vars.Find(e => e.Name == s).Change(value);` won't work the same for value types and reference types.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. My bad. I wasn't paying attention when writing this question and in Rextester I copied code and deleted unnecessary parts. I oversaw it. I edited it now. Why does Find works differently for classes and structs? Is changing `Var` to a class the only option?

Comment: For a struct, it returns a copy, so the original value is not changed; https://dotnetfiddle.net/mqVK1p

Comment: Oh! Okay. I didn't know that! Thank you.

Comment: @SkillGG Everything works differently for classes and structs. Not just Find. Structs are value types, not reference types. That affects Find. It affects a lot of other things too.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't know that. I just thought that structs are non-nullable and that's it. I will have to learn a bit more about them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@wimh figured it out:

`.Find()` used with structs returns copy and does not change the original. [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mqVK1p)

Thanks

Code that fixed it, yet `Var` still remained a struct:

```
vars[vars.FindIndex(e => e.Name == s)] = new Var(s, value);
```

instead of

```
vars.Find(e=>e.Name==s).Change(value);
```

And I got rid of `Var.Change` as it was not useful anymore.